# Printing page uses wrong media query breakpoint

Tags: css, media-queries, css-paged-media

I'm working on a 'print preview' page where we're rendering a separate HTML document so the user can then print it.

I'm running into an issue where printing to 8.5 x 11, it's taking on media query viewport styles <800px.

I can 'fix' this by printing to a tabloid sheet, which is using the desktop (default) CSS.

I'm a bit rusty in my media queries and CSS but...is it standard that the printing process from the browser would adapt a particular media query size?

Is there a simple workaround for this? I could over-ride all of the media query CSS but given this is a large enterprise piece of bloated software, that's a challenge and only bloating our CSS anymore. Is there a way to say "when printing this, print at the desktop width..."

Comment: See `print` media type here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: @Michael_B to be clear, we don't want to use the print media query. We *could* but we've already built CSS for the page, and are trying to avoid redundant CSS when we don't need it.